# Блок с текстом уходит влево

Tags: html, css

Вот детище моё: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vYhy-xU_pa7aKbQB_UiaVDJz3wibjQur
Самый нижний div при уменьшении ширины экрана сильно уходит влево. К примеру: div который выше находится от самого низкого так не уходит. Как это исправить?

Comment: для того что бы Вам помогли выкладывайте код в сниппет stackoverflow, картинки можно заменить такими как https://placehold.it и по вопросу, у вас есть инлайновый css в html - в общем устраните замечания и потом поговорим о том почем у вас так как вы не хотите

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас верхнее меню отталкивается от правого края

```
right: 14%
```

А у нижнего текста стоит :

```
left: 38%;
```

и отталкивается от левого края

Comment: Не получается :(